# Can cat understand if we try to communicate in cat's language by mimicking sounds that cats make in different situations to communicate?

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology, aggression, communication

First of all my apology to those readers who have little or no experience with cats and don't know the meaning of a numerous numbers and types of cat vocalizations and gestures.

This may sound absurd but I am quite curious, here I find lots of questions about how to make my cat not do this. And there are lots of suggestions. But what if we can say a cat NO in cat's language, by mimicking warning sounds and gestures that cats make.

Today morning I was working on my laptop but Bhutu (my cat) was not letting me to work. I don't know the reason but she was growling at me. She was biting my hand. Hitting my hand with her paws, and constantly growling at me. But I have done nothing.

I said, NO, again NO, ....., then NO in a stern voice. But no impact, my cat was completely ignoring me.

Then I did a gnawwww sound, like that of cat's growling, and phasssss, like that of cat's hissing.

Immediately Bhutu stopped, her ears went back, her tails below her tummy, and she sat down like a good girl by the side of my laptop. And I started to work peacefully.

It's like I am making her realize who is the ALPHA.

This is even more odd, as cats do not have any alpha, it's dog who has it.

But here Bhutu is not like moving away after defeat, she is accepting my dominance and sitting back.

**NOTE:**

It may be noted that I brought my cat when she was one and a half months old, and she is now almost two years old. Ever since I brought my cat, I have played with her like a kitten plays with her litter-mate. And she does all her cat like things mostly with me. To others she behaves like a normal cat.

I don't know whether this information is of any significance or not.

Comment: cats are attracted to the pc because you are giving it attention so it have to be interesting,it is the same if you assemble a cat tree too your cat will be at your side intervening with your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made bad experiences with this approach.

Our cats are not allowed to jump or walk on tables, but it takes time to teach them. Usually we would use a water spray bottle, but when it wasn't at hand, I looked our cat directly in the eyes and made a hissing sound.

She understood and didn't walk on the table, but she connected the negative experience with *me* and not with *the table*. Since I took my role as teacher seriously, I hissed at her several times, which lead to her not liking me much anymore.

In retrospect, I would have prefered to reprimand her in a neutral way (water spray bottle) so she doesn't connect the negative experience with me in person.

Comment: Cats will learn you are the source of the spray bottle as well, and resent you for that.  This is why many say that negative reinforcement doesn't work.  They will resent the human for it, and they learn to just do it while you aren't there, which isn't what you want.  The only effective negative reinforcement are things that happen not by the human triggering them, and even when the human isn't there, for example, there are motion detecting devices that makes a noise they don't like.  At best, making a sudden loud noise can help to distract the cat from whatever it's doing.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to mimic cat sounds is not effective for me (I do not understand the full meaning of all of the cat sounds).

When I communicate with my cat I use my normal words but I try to keep it simple for my cat to understand.

Like do you want (I get her full attention by saying this) food/treats/to go outside/to go to bed, simple things that a cat can understand the meaning of.

I have seen cats will have problems when words sound the same. So this is something you need to be aware of.

Training a cat to understand what you mean is something that will take time, but during this time you will learn a lot from your cat too about what she/he thinks is important and what she/he likes.

A cat will often give you vocal feedback by answering when you talk to her/him and this can be helpful as you know you have the attention of your cat.

I do only need to say the name of my cat and she comes running to me, so she knows her name and she has the need to see what I want.

This training and learning never stops and it might feel slow at times but you need to know a cat will never forget what she/he has learned.

You will learn that a cat uses different sounds to answer yes or no.

Comment: I am confident that I can understand at least 50 vocalization patterns and 50 gestures for my cat Bhutu.